# How do you yank X number of characters in vim?

Tags: vim

I know I can cut 5 characters in vim by typing `5x`, and I often use this to copy and paste text by doing `5xu` then pasting them somewhere else.

I am lazy and would rather just yank the 5 characters so I don't have to undo the cut action.

How can I do this?

Comment: `x` is just a shortcut for `dl`.

Comment: @Cory: I updated my answer with a key mapping. Not sure if it's helpful, but I realized that your old method (`5xu`) didn't really use any more keystrokes than the "technically correct" `y5l`, so there's not too much help there.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Yank supports standard movement commands. Use <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> (<- that's a lowercase L)

And if you want to yank 5 characters backwards, use <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>h</kbd>.

Now, if you're feeling *really* lazy, remap this particular sequence to a key-combination, like so:

```
:nnoremap <C-l> y5l
```

In this case, "yank 5 to the right" gets mapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (lowercase L).

---

If you'd like, you can also use <kbd>Space</kbd> instead of <kbd>L</kbd> to yank characters in the forward direction (examples: <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> for a single character or <kbd>5</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> for 5). Some people may find it to be quicker or easier than hitting <kbd>L</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is it possible to select a range of letters to be copied, instead of specifying a number for the range? Like we can press shift and move the cursor in MS Word. Thanks!

Comment: @yuqli: If I understand your question correctly, you're asking if it's possible to manually "select" a set of characters to copy? If so, then you want to use "visual mode". Just press `v` to enter visual mode, which will begin selecting, then move the cursor using the normal movement keys, and finally press `y` to copy.

Answer (score 17):

This is complementing the answer of [voithos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7520692/2805305):

You can also use <kbd>5</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> (ty @hauleth for suggestion)

This is useful for me especially when I want to yank just one character:

<kbd>y</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>

Is easier (for me at least) to find and hit <kbd>Space</kbd> than <kbd>l</kbd>.

Comment: `5y<Space>` will yank all 5 chars.

Comment: y+space is really useful for copying a single character. You should edit voithos's answer to include that.

Comment: Some char occupy more than one column, like TABs, so you may end up at 5th column with less than 5 chars.

Answer (score 10):

Found this post because I too  wanted to yank `x` number characters                                  without cutting and learned this while testing.

There may be times when is easier to look for certain characters than to count the number of characters to yank.

Enter the motions `t` and `T`.

Think `ytx` as `yank forward to character x`

Think `yTx` as `yank backward to character x`

[image]

Comment: was looking for how to "yank to" backwards (my first thought was Y t .. but it's y T) thanks!!

Answer (score -7):

`y5` will do it. `yy` yanks lines, `y` yanks characters.

Comment: `y5` is an incomplete action, isn't it? You have to specify 5 _what_. Five characters to the right? `y5l` Five characters to the left? `y5h` Etc.